# How can design my applications to take advantage of Azure but prevent being locked in?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, azure

I am starting to migrate a couple of applications to Azure. Seems very straightforward and all I have to do is add an addiitonal Azure project to my solution and point it at my web project.

However what concerns me is that the team starts contaminating my applications with Azure specific functionality and relying on it. For example File uploads would be to Azure storage, azure caching etc. All well and good if we stay Azure and all clients are happy to use Azure. If we find a client isn't happy with Azure I'd like not be into a lot of work removing Azure functionality.

Just wondering if anyone had experience similar issues. I guess ideally I'd like to be able to have the project right publish to Azure and it uses Azure features, Azure Code etc and a second publish that just allows me to use IIS with non Azure features.

I assume I just need to be careful use interfaces correctly and DI etc. FileUpload vs AzureFileUpload. What about issues like resources coming from Azure storage for CSS/scripts etc rather than local? Should I look at using Azure Cloud Drive to simulate just standard NTFS environment

Is there any advice/patterns/practices? Has anyone experiences with similar? How about separating projects up and project structure etc? I guess a lot of is it just standard design. Just wondering how other people were approaching avoiding lock in with Azure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple things you can do if you're concerned:

1. Stick to the core technologies like asp.net, ado.net, sql which also exist outside of Azure.
2. Abstract away code which uses Azure specific services.

For the first one, simply scan your code to ensure the runtime services don't include Azure namespaces.

But, to be a cloud like service and get it's benefit, you should look into adopting azure services.

For the second, you can create a cloud services layer abstracted away by an interface.  Only that layer communicates with azure specific services.  If you need to work outside of azure, you just need a plug-in for that layer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the app to be able to run on IIS or Azure, and those are your only 2 targets, my only advice is don't overdo the abstracting / interfaces. There are some differences that can be handled in web.config and WebRole.OnStart(), such as using cache as a session provider or logging diagnostics to table storage.

Some things it will help to create interfaces for, and then inject those interfaces in the config depending on your deploy target (web config transform is what we use). For example in IIS you might want to send an email in a separate thread, whereas in Azure you might use a worker role and a queue. You can set up a web.config transform with 1 implementation of ISendEmails for IIS, and different one for Azure.

Another thing you could do, depending on how much file data you have, is store files as blob columns in the db. I'm sure someone will tell me this isn't good for performance, and can get expensive with GB of file data in sql sever, and they have a point. It may be worth considering though if having IIS/Azure flexibility is of high concern.

Answer (score 0):

I would design a cloud interface (as an abstraction of an actual cloud/network) that your applications can use, together with an Azure implementation of that interface.

Then later, when needed, you can make other cloud implementations that your apps can use using the same interface.

When designing the interface, the challenge is to include only generic methods that are relevant on every kind of cloud/network. So this will prevent using any Azure specific features directly by your applications, but that is exactly the purpose.